# Cant get css animations to work

Tags: html, css

I have been trying lots to get some CSS animations to work. I made an opacity animation which worked fine
but using the "left" property and also this (which I found off the internet and tried to use) it still didn't work:

```
        @-webkit-keyframes slideInLeft {
      0% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
      transform: translateX(-100%);
      visibility: visible;
      }
      100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      transform: translateX(0);
      }

      }
      @keyframes slideInLeft {
      0% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
      transform: translateX(-100%);
      visibility: visible;
      }
      100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      transform: translateX(0);
      }


    #about h1 {
      display:block;
      font-family:Montserrat, Verdana, sans-serif;
      text-align:left;
      color:ghostwhite;
      font-size:50px;
      -webkit-animation-name: slideInLeft;
        animation-name: slideInLeft;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
        animation-fill-mode: both;
    }


    #about p {
      display:block;
      font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;
      text-align:left;
      color:whitesmoke;
      font-size:17.5px;
      -webkit-animation-name: slideInLeft;
        animation-name: slideInLeft;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
        animation-fill-mode: both;
    }

    #prev-work h1 {
      display:block;
      font-family:Montserrat, Verdana, sans-serif;
      text-align:left;
      color:rgba(39,39,39,1);
      font-size:50px;
      -webkit-animation-name: slideInLeft;
        animation-name: slideInLeft;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
        animation-fill-mode: both;
    }


    #prev-work p {
      display:block;
      font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;
      text-align:left;
      color:rgba(39,39,39,1);
      font-size:17.5px;
      -webkit-animation-name: slideInLeft;
        animation-name: slideInLeft;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
        animation-fill-mode: both;
    }

section {
  top:100%;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
section .mid {
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  background-color:#272727;
}
```

HTML

```
  <section>
    <div class="mid">
      <div class="margin-90">
        <div id="about">
          <h1>Title...</h1>
          <p>Text...
          </p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
```

Site Link: http://vividstudios.x10.mx/

Comment: I don't see the `left` property being used anywhere there. Could you please post the code that is not working?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rrwgxzq0/ ... it's just a typo ... you are missing one `}` closer after the last `@keyframes` declaration ... voting to close

Comment: Yeah I removed the left one

Comment: Still Doesn't work

Comment: check the fiddle it works ... if doesn't work try to replicate your issue on jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qock9zst/

Comment: As I said it's just that typo https://jsfiddle.net/qock9zst/1/

Comment: I think you missed a `}`.
see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qock9zst/2/

Comment: Look at my site where all of the source code is: http://vividstudios.x10.mx/

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1.Plz add 2nd keyframes close bracket ( **}** ). 
The closing bracket is main problem!!

2.Change **top:100%** to **top:0;** on **section & section .mid** in css

Sorry for bad english :(